# Response Value Does Not Return After Successfully Login With CURL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, curl

I had problem which is I cannot get response value even though sign in into rails app using curl post going through. This is my CURL command:

**curl -i -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X POST http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in -d '{"user": {"email": "admin@admin.com", "password": "abc12345"}}'**

and this is http status I got:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Etag: W/"fa9a29286a105efca890fba3ae3fc084"
Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
X-Request-Id: a4ecab97-f7fe-4354-834a-f2ac07faa871
X-Runtime: 0.332680
Server: WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/2.0.0/2014-05-08)
Date: Wed, 29 Jul 2015 16:24:05 GMT
Content-Length: 8205
Connection: Keep-Alive
Set-Cookie: request_method=POST; path=/
Set-Cookie: _stuckplaces_session=WmNOeUxyMW9Mc1M3aUx0R3J5U29ZUU85bzJoeEF5T0dCb0F3eG9GdVdsV2hMUGtRSFhIVnRZWHI3bXNKbnlZUTF2c0NJNVQxeEdMYldNSEl5WEVGZlU0dHJWYUNFVWx2bDVaRXJCdWcvd29ZWlRwMHJ6SnhjeHRHeDRmNFByVjI0a1dhbTZZWkxnb0t6Ky9LYnZtTFVZOFE1Tk8vQ1B4T0ZkUG00UGpyU0dpK2NZcUVhLzY1MzhMMnhGZTZ2UkFaOC9VTzNKZXFGQ3B1dWFpcmV3M2JZU1FUdUNnWjhqOUhvbld0M3B2eHdrSVRNT1BNV1ZpSjdQQTVoYkFNMjJYdC0tZktIaFBDc1VZVVltM29mVDU2eDlLUT09--cbf739d14b947b3631d82f2c6d1283a95bede14b; path=/; HttpOnly
```

and what I expected for response value is something like this

***HTTP/1.1 200 OK
{"response":{"user_id":2,"token":"6c54adfb9fd41e33738f3b3707e9726b"}}
view raw***

I hope something could help me with this problem, thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you using Devise for authentication?

Comment: Yes, I'm using devise.

Comment: Have you made any changes to the Devise controller actions for them to respond in JSON?

Comment: No, I did not make any changes to the Devise controller actions to make them respond in JSON. But I made a new file name sessions_controller.rb. Here is the code for sessions_controller. gist.github.com/afiq90/ca1fd545821469f2865d

Comment: No response of the requested type is being returned...

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your sessions controller to respond with JSON containing the required response. You can use [this link](https://gist.github.com/afiq90/ca1fd545821469f2865d) for reference.